# Keeping track of Stack depth for debugging

Tags: java, eclipse

I am confused with how can i 'keep track of stack depth'. Actually, this question relates to the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11157985/1010943 on one of my question. The answer was correct and understood but i wasnt able to understand the TIP. The google search also does not reveal any useful information. Bytheway, if it matters then i am using Eclipse IDE

Comment: Are you referring to the call stack or the data structure known as a stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep track of stack depth by including a depth param in your recursive function, or using Thread.getStackTrace()

Comment: Thanks , I have done it with depth param and have been trying to use the getStackTrace but am not able to crack that. Any hints (piece of code )

Answer (score 3):

Just add an int parameter called (say) depth.
On your first call to your recursive function, pass in depth=0.
Whenever you recurse, pass through depth+1.
Therefore depth is always how many times you've recursed so far.

Or you could do some nasty checking of the methods on the call stack, but I wouldn't go down that route! ;]

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getStackTrace()

> Returns an array of stack trace elements representing the stack dump
>   of this thread. This method will return a zero-length array if this
>   thread has not started or has terminated. If the returned array is of
>   non-zero length then the first element of the array represents the top
>   of the stack, which is the most recent method invocation in the
>   sequence. The last element of the array represents the bottom of the
>   stack, which is the least recent method invocation in the sequence.